# get_permalink() return duplicate URL during loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show some posts in my slider; But this loop returns same link for all items

```
$recent_posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => '6‍', 'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'));
foreach ($recent_posts as $post_item) : ?>
    <?php $author_id = $post->post_author; ?>
        <a href="<?= get_permalink($post) ?>" class="special-slide">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_item, 'full'); 
        </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small mistake on the 4th line: you're calling `get_permalink($post)` where `$post` is set for the current page, where you should have used `get_permalink($post_item)` - where `$post_item` is the variable from your loop.

(You're also making the same mistake on the 3rd line when you're trying to get the author_id as well)